# Querying many-to-many relationship filtering by many to many table but ordering by an associated table's field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, many-to-many

I am trying to come up with a query for a many-to-many relationship with filtering for a certain field in the many-to-many table while ordering by a field in an associated table.

How do I get all the active firm_emps of a specific firm and order the firm_emps by user's name?

user.rb

```
Class User < ApplicationRecord
 has_many :firm_emps, :dependent => :destroy
 has_many :firms, through: :firm_emps
end
```

user.rb migration file

```
...
t.string :name
t.boolean :active
...
```

firm_emp.rb

```
Class FirmEmp < ApplicationRecord
 belongs_to :firm
 belongs_to :user
end
```

firm_emp.rb's migration file

```
...
 t.belongs_to :user, index: true
 t.belongs_to :firm, index: true
 t.boolean :admin, default: false
 t.boolean :active, default: true
...
```

firm.rb

```
Class Firm < ApplicationRecord
 has_many :firm_emps, dependent: :destroy
 has_many :users, through: :firm_emps
end
```

Firm.rb's migration file

```
...
t.string :full_name
t.boolean :active
...
```

I've tried the following queries in rails console:

```
f = Firm.first
f.users.where(active: true).order('users.name asc')
# But this filters on User's table field active: true and not the FirmEmps table field active: true

f.users.joins(:firmemps).where(active: true).order('users.name asc')
# Just doesn't work
f.firm_emps.active.order('firm_emps.active')
# But i can't order by user's field 'name'
```

**EDIT:** 
@PragyaSriharsh's and @ArunEapachen's answers worked.

Comment: If name is present in only one of all tables, then you can use it as `f.users.where(active: true).order(name: :asc)` (order all by firm name), otherwise pass the underscored plural name of the table.

Comment: f.users.joins(:firm_emps).where('firm_emps.active=?', true).order('users.name asc') . If it doesn't work use sort_by method.

Comment: @SebastianPalma, if you notice, all 3 tables have a field 'active'. Your query filters on 'active = true' on users' table and not on firm_emp's table.

Comment: @PragyaSriharsh, your answer worked for me and I"d like to upvote your answer but you gave your answer as a comment. If you click the 'answer question' button I can set your answer as correct.

Comment: __If name is present in only one of all tables__, that was written before you updated the question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try the following.

```
f = Firm.first
f.users.where('firm_epms.active = ?' , true).order('users.name asc')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
f.users.joins(:firm_emps).where('firm_emps.active=?', true).order('users.name asc')
```

If it doesn't work use sort_by method.